# Sqlalchemy User Product Reviews Relation model deisgn

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Need models so that a User can have a Products and Users can leave Reviews on Products made by other users. I was thinking having a one to many relationship from products to reviews but then how do which users left which review. This is what i have so far.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    products =  db.relationship('Product', backref='products',
                                lazy='dynamic')


class Review(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    stars =  db.Column(db.String(255))
    description =  db.Column(db.String(255))


class Product(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: What if you just add a foreign key constraint to the `Review` class that points to `Product.id`?

Comment: But then how  would i know which User left which Review?

Comment: The one-to-many relationship you're thinking of adding should cover that for you, right?

Comment: Yes I need to know which User Left which review on which product. Thank you coralv for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add foreign keys for `User` and `Product` into your `Review` table:

```
class Review(db.Model):
    # ... 
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

You can also then add backrefs for `Reviews` on to your `User` and `Product`, and you can filter the `user.reviews` by `product_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining setting it up like this (with the new one-to-many included as well - I think I've got that right).  You should know the product's ID at the time you're creating the entry in the Python code, so you can simply add it in.  I don't think you would necessarily need to create a relationship for that.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    products =  db.relationship('Product', backref='user',
                            lazy='dynamic')
    reviews= db.relationship("Review", backref="user", lazy='dynamic')


class Review(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    stars =  db.Column(db.String(255))
    description =  db.Column(db.String(255))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class Product(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

I changed a line in your `User` class.  You had

```
products =  db.relationship('Product', backref='product',
                            lazy='dynamic')
```

But I think it's supposed to be

```
products =  db.relationship('Product', backref='user',
                            lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: Yeah i could add it but i still need a slot to put it in. Might as well have it done automatically. I dont "need it but i should built it as best as i can"